# JS: how to prevent navigation/changing page on site?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to create a SAP from an existing site

I try to intercept every page change, to add some routing and some JS loading content.

I tried it with : beforeunload

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But it does not seem to work : the event is triggered but url and page is changed.
Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, since people could maliciously keep you on a page in order to track you or download malware

Comment: you could when navigating in your SPA, use pushHistory but that only gets so far.

Comment: ok, but what about keeping the same domain name ?

Comment: Have you considered using something like nodejs and the 'fetch' api?  With this combo you could send fetch request for page changes and then respond with only the data you want changed. Once the data is received on the client side, you can then manipulate the DOM with client side JS, deleting and adding elements as required.

Comment: You can't just block unload events like that. `beforeunload` only supports a confirm dialog that lets the user choose to stay on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If the page change is happening by clicking a <a> link, which redirect to another url, simply include **e.preventDefault();** :

```
<a class="specificAnchorLinkClass" role="link" href="something.html/myPage">Link Text</a>
```

---

```
function goToNewPage(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // code to fetch/load new page
}

var specificAnchorLinks = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('specificAnchorLinkClass'));
specificAnchorLinks.map(x => x.addEventListener('click', goToNewPage);
```

I am also using a personal SPA-ish implementation, and I use this for preventing navigation away from the root page, while still including the <a> tags for semantic and accessibility purposes.

If you want to redirect to another page, but work with the url itself :

```
function goToNewPage(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newUrl = // do something to modify existing url, through  window.location
    window.location.href = newUrl // navigates to the new link
}
```

or

```
function goToNewPage(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newUrl = // do something to modify existing url, through  window.location
    history.pushState(null, null, newUrl) // stays on the same page, but pushes the url as if navigating to a different page
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sounds good. And How do you handle forms posting or JS window.location functions ? Should be nice to have it all handled with a librtary

Comment: You can do the same for the forms with the "submit" event, but for the window.location if you can't modify the code it will not be easy because browsers not allow this method altering.

Comment: My implementation doesn't handle forms atm, not that it couldn't.  I have also tried onbeforeunload when I first started out, but it can't be prevented in itself, so it's not usefull for such. For the scope of the question, I've given the approach I use to prevent navigating away from the root page. For loading a new page, a simple fetch request for the page's HTML file and a history.pushState takes care of my use cases.

Comment: My implementation mimics a SPA functionality, while still fetching a 'new page's' HTML file and adding it's content to the view (basically a hibrid between SPA and multi-page). It allows for the general resources to be loaded at start and then only get the individual pages, with all the functionality already present without having to get it all over again, while not needing to download the whole application's files from the start (where a large number of pages might not be ever visited). It was a nice exercise, and it's working out for me for the limited cases I use it in.